# Send/get a string data from Android device to Windows CE device?

Tags: java, android, serial-port, windows-ce, tlv

How send/get a string data from android device to Windows CE device using RS232 with JAVA codes?

```
String A="002A123456789123456789123456FF8A631ADF0215DF820803000004DF820903080317DF820A03163201DF4153";
```

Comment: what did you already try ?

Comment: I couldn't find any data so nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used UsbSerialLibrary acording to directions at link.

[UsbSerialLibrary](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android)

Comment: Using this library I am getting empty drivers list. Did you get any success? And what was the Android OS version in which you got succeed?